# Provide remote console access to a local rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, remote-access, remote-debugging

I need to interview remote rails techs for their job application, and I would like to offer an interactive exercise where the candidates have to do an exercise in the console.

I would like to run a rails application on my own computer, and provide a remote access to my console (eg. using ngrok to make localhost available) so the candidate can connect to my console, send commands and see the outputs of each command.

Remote debugging often involve connecting to SSH to run a console through the SSH connection, but here I'd be looking for a simple client/server redirection of the input to the candidate's console.

When I crash a rails web application, the browser spawns a web console that seems to do quite what I want. Is it possible to reuse or have something like that for my use case ?

Question : how can I let a user from the internet connect to my Rails console to execute some commands that both he and I will see ?

Comment: _When I crash a rails web application, the browser spawns a web console that seems to do exactly what I want_ you are talking about `web-console` gem, check it out

Comment: Yes I was referring to that gem (included by default in recent Rails version). If I understand well, this gem acts as a mini-server that keeps track of the current ruby context, and can be interacted with.

Comment: I feel you don't have a concrete programming question. Have you tried implementing some solution? SO wouldn't help you otherwise.

Comment: You might be better served by a simple screen sharing app, maybe coupled with a screen recording app - your interviewees would get to work in their environment, in which they're probably much more comfortable, and you still get to follow what they do in real time.

Comment: I often have bad surprises with screen sharing app (video quality, etc.) and I don't see how it would help here. I want to serve my code my code and let the candidate work on it, so during the videocall I can ask the question and see how the candidate reacts.

I will reformulate so my programming questions appears more explicitely.

Comment: I think your idea is a good one, and I share your concern with screen sharing apps. However, I still second the suggestion to use a screen sharing app. You could cobble together something yourself that might allow you to do what you want, but it may not be any more reliable than a screen sharing app. Zoom works well for me on Ubuntu 16.04 and my business partner on Windows 10. They have a free option.

Comment: I don't even understand how screen sharing really helps... So the guys tells you or write you something that you write in turn in your console and he sees the output directly in the screen ?

Comment: There are lots of good online tools like interviewing.io and screenhero. If you want console sharing I would recommend a tool like https://tmate.io/